# Formula for calculating an Ephemeris table

Tags: algorithm, datetime

Here's an obscure question:

I need to be able to determine historical astrological periods (semi) accurately. I am looking for a way to calculate the start and end dates of a given zodiac sign period given a geographical coordinate and a year.

The purpose of the algorithm is to determine the possible dates of birth for a person whose astrological sign, year and place of birth is known for the [Open Ancestry project](http://bitbucket.org/grenade/openancestry). I will convert the implementation to C#.

Does anyone know of a semi reliable source for an existing [Ephemeris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeris) table or a way to create one programmatically? I really just need a start point so it doesn't matter if the geographical parts of the formula or table are missing as long as the mechanism for approximating the start and end (given a specific year) are shown.

The programming language for an algorithmic approach is not important.

Comment: @paxdiablo Most of the resources I have found, including the US Navy one, tend to be interested in contemporary tables whereas I need to compute or find data for the last several hundred years.

Comment: Will anyone notice if you get it wrong? Clearly a double-blind test is called for.

Comment: @Nick Johnson, The algorithm is part of a wider project to turn collections of human stories ("Being a Libra, my aunt was always weighing up the consequences..") into genealogical links. Ancestral links are often just collections of such stories passed from generation to generation. The Open Ancestry project is making an effort to draw the world family tree by algorithmically analysing those stories. People might not notice inaccuracies in the algorithm but over time a bad algorithm will yield useless data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you look at the source of [stellarium](http://www.stellarium.org/) (was able to go quite far in the past)? I am sure the whole thing is an overkill for you, but maybe you can dig up their resources or contact somebody involved with it?